# Javascript Submit Form Not Submitting

Tags: javascript

I created a form name="form" and and included a submit button

```
<button type="submit" id="create" onclick=" go();" name="create">Create</button>
```

This is my function go()

```
function go() {

    $("#create").prop("disabled", true);
    document.forms["form"].submit();

}
```

The function did disable the button, however, it did not submit the form. Help.

Comment: Your sample HTML has the form named "create", not "form".

Comment: create is my form submit button name. My form name is form <form method="post" action="" name="form"></form>

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you wrapped it in the form however you need to give the button the type Submit and the form the `go()` function like so:

```
<form name="form" onSubmit="go()">
  <input type="submit" id="create" value="Create" />
</form>
```